# Jump to specific page in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a multipage reporting services report, and i would like to start from a specific page, not page one as default.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://myrsserver/reportserver?http://portal/reports/sample%20reports/departmental%20sales.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rc:Zoom=Whole%20Page&rc:Parameters=collapsed&rc:DocMap=true&rc:**Section=999**

Where "Section" parameter is your Page Number.

In the HTML Viewer, there are many options available that can be used to controlling report rendering.  This is a short list of the of the ones you’re likely to find useful:

```
* rs:Format – Rendering modes you can pass are HTML3.2, HTML4.0, MHTML, IMAGE, EXCEL, WORD, CSV, PDF, XML, defaults to HTML4.0
* rc:Zoom – Specified in percentages, supports Page Width and Whole Page, defaults to 100%
* rc:Toolbar – True/False, used to show/hide the toolbar, defaults to true
* rc:Parameters – True/False/Collapsed, used to show/hide/collapse the parameters in the toolbar, defaults to true
* rc:DocMap – True/False, used to show/hide document map, defaults to true (not shown unless report has document map)
* rc:Section – Specifies default page number to display, defaults to 1
* rc:BookMarkID – Jumps to a specific bookmark in a report
* rc:FindString – Provides search criteria to the report and finds the first instance of the string specified
```